# Factoring without need to guess the extension

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

To provide a simple example (but I need more complicated ones): I want to factor `x^2-6x*y+y^2`. After solving `x^2-6x*y+y^2==0` I see that the expressions for roots involve `Sqrt[2]`, so I say `Factor[x^2 - 6x*y + y^2, Extension -> Sqrt[2]]` and get what I want, namely `-(x+(-3+2Sqrt[2])y) (-x+(3+2Sqrt[2])y)`.

But is there a command that would factor directly, finding the needed extension itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = x^2 - 6 x*y + y^2;

expr2 = Collect[#, y] & /@ (Times @@ (x - SolveValues[expr == 0, x]))

(* (x + (-3 - 2 Sqrt[2]) y) (x + (-3 + 2 Sqrt[2]) y) *)

expr == expr2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```